# jQuery messages validator its not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im doing a basic login system with jQuery and it seems everything fine for me, but Im always entering im my jquery here: `alert('Error in system');`.

But its very strange because When I do this `alert(answer);` its showing all my data of my `$_SESSION['userlogin']`.

Somebody there understand what might be wrong?

Im have this jQuery to show validator messages in a login form:

```
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var login = $(this).serialize() + '&action=login';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'switch/login.php',
            data: login,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(answer){
                if(answer == 'errorEmpty'){
                    $('.msg').empty().html('<p class="warning">Informe seu usuário e senha!</p>').fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else if (answer == 'errorPass'){
                    $('.msg').empty().html('<p class="error">Error ,wrong pass or username!</p>').fadeIn('slow');

                }
                else if(answer == 'sucess'){
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        $(location).attr('href','dashboard.php');
                 },1000);
               }
                else{
                    alert('Error in system');
                }
                alert(answer);
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loginbox h1 img').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('.loginbox h1 img').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error in system');
            }

       });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Then I have my php file:

```
switch ($action){
    case 'login':
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        if(!$user || !$pass){
            echo 'errorEmpty';
        }else{  
            $searchUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE login=:login AND pass=:pass"); 
            $searchUser->bindValue(":login", $user);  
            $searchUser->bindValue(":pass", $pass); 
            $searchUser->execute();
            $num_rows = $searchUser->rowCount();
            $result = $pesquisaUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($num_rows>=1){

                $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $result;
                echo 'sucess';
                print_r($_SESSION['userlogin']);
            }
            else{
                echo 'errorPass';
            }
        }
    break;
    default:
        echo 'Error';

}
```

Comment: have you tried with put `return` statement after `echo sucsses` like `echo 'sucess'; return;`?

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I really thought that wasn´t necessary in this situation. Can you give the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `return;` after `echo sucess` statement, I think the problem is `print_r($_SESSION['userlogin']);`.

After placed the `return;` the `print_r` will not executed.

```
echo 'sucess';
return;
```

Comment: You are right, the problem was really that! Thanks :)